# How to retrieve Oauth1.0 woocommerce API?

Tags: java, android, woocommerce

Am trying to retrieve API from the woocommerce website and I don't know how to retrieve.

http://aspira.opendoorstech.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?

Consumer Key =xxxxxxxxxx
Consumer Secret =xxxxxxxxxx

I don't have the access token am just trying it for the first time.

Anyone help how to retrieve this API in the android studio.

Comment: Do you have header information about the link? If you know the auth token then pass it through header

Comment: no, i don't have the access token

Comment: where to find this class OAuthProvider.class for using scribe

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're looking in the wrong place. Also nothing to do with Android nor Java.

[image]